# PHP loop add div around items between a count

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach

I'm using the following working code to wrap every 3 elements in a div:

```
$count = 1

foreach( $names as $name ):

  if ($count%3 == 1) {
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
  }

  echo $name;

  if ($count%3 == 0) {
    echo '</div>';
  }

  $count++;

endforeach;

if ($count%3 != 1) echo "</div>";
```

That returns:

```
<div class="wrap">
  name
  name
  name
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  name
  name
  name
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  name
  name
  name
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  name
  name
  name
</div>
```

So far so good.. but i want the second wrapped set to have 4 "name" elements like so:

```
<div class="wrap">
  name
  name
  name
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  name
  name
  name
  name
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  name
  name
  name
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  name
  name
  name
</div>
```

Every 3 items should be wrapped in the div, except the second set which will have 4 items.

Or another way to explain: items 4 to 8 will be wrapped in a div while every other 3 items will be wrapped in div.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add special cases for the first two DIVs, and adjust the modulus for the ones after that.

```
$count = 1

foreach( $names as $name ):
    if ($count == 1 || $count == 4 || ($count > 5 && $count % 3 == 2)) {
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
    }
    echo $name;
    if ($count == 3 || $count == 7 || ($count > 7 && $count % 3 == 1)) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
    $count++;
endforeach;
// Finish the last block -- lots of different cases
if ($count < 4 || ($count > 4 && $count < 8) || ($count > 8 && $count % 3 != 2)) {
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is now wrapping div within divs. What should the last one be after the `endforeach;`?`if ($count%3 != 1) echo "</div>";` I use that to make sure the div is closed

Comment: I added that to the answer, it's actually the trickiest part!

Comment: And I got it wrong at first, because I forgot that we incremented `$count` already. It should be right now.

Comment: Hmm this is strange. It returns the first wrap set with 3 items which is ok but the second wrap set has the remaining wrap sets within it.

Comment: Hmm this is strange. It returns the first wrap set with 3 items which is ok but the second wrap set has the remaining wrap sets within it.

Comment: Needed to change `>4` to `>5` because `5%3 == 2`